# Assigning a filter to an object variable in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have an `ng-repeat` using a filter like this:

```
#1
<div class="contestReports" ng-repeat="contest in contests | filter:{votingOver:true}">
    <contestreport></contestreport>
</div>
```

I want to allow the customer to be able to filter it so I have assigned the filter to a variable like this:

```
#2
<div ng-init="reportFilter = {votingOver:true}"></div>
<div class="contestReports" ng-repeat="contest in contests | filter:reportFilter">
    <contestreport></contestreport>
</div>
```

Code `#1` is working but Code `#2` is not and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Please have a look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/nFFHmUA7RdxMIPV9VUDC?p=preview

Comment: That is searching by plaintext and not an object filter

Comment: in general ngInit is not a good practice to use anyway - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit, or it's more of a theoretical question for you?

Comment: Works in this [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ygxs1ff/).

Comment: @Jordash don't you interested in give a bounty? Have you checked answers?

Answer (score 3):

Did you also try to wrap `ng-init`

```
<div ng-init="(reportFilter = '{votingOver:true}')"></div>
```

However, as I've stated in my comment earlier - [angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) states that using ngInit is a bad practice in mostly all cases. So that should not be a solution to your problem if possible.

And your #2 code actually works, please check this plunk - http://plnkr.co/edit/dBDyYPd3ZoUVdXngu52t?p=preview

```
//html
  <div ng-init="reportFilter = {votingOver:false}"></div>
<div class="contestReports" ng-repeat="contest in contests | filter:reportFilter">
  {{contest | json}}
</div>

  </div>

//js in controller
  $scope.contests = [
    {id:1, title:'1', votingOver:false},
    {id:2, title:'2', votingOver:true},
    {id:3, title:'3', votingOver:true}
    ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [**`ng-init` is not a good way to go with**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)(as you can see angular docs has added warning text in red). As you know it is going to evaluate on initial rendering only(as `ng-init` evaluates its expression in `preLink` phase).

By looking at your code, it seems like `reportFilter` variable is going to be an common object for all `contests`. Correct me if I'm wrong?

I'd add this value inside a controller only once like below.

```
//place this inside your controller
$scope.reportFilter = { votingOver : true };
```

And use directly on view itself.

```
<div class="contestReports" ng-repeat="contest in contests | filter:reportFilter">
    <contestreport></contestreport>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to save the result of applying filter to the json data in a variable before ng-repeat reads items in the jsonArray like below.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-init="contests=
        [{name:'bad apple', votingOver:false},
         {name:'pleasurebuilder', votingOver:true},
        {votingOver:true}]">
  </div>
  <div ng-init="reportFilter = {votingOver:true}">
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="contest in revoluza = (contests | filter: reportFilter)">
    {{contest}}
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Code 2 is not working because you have to create custom filter while you are only intializing div not creating filter

Code 1 is working because you are using proper syntax for default filter that can be compared with any object just like you did